# ExpressJS + jsdom — Scope Issue

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, jsdom

I have an expressJS web app with routes set up. I also have several functions that exist within a jsdom environment because of various jquery functions that I want to take advantage of.

The issue I'm having is that I need to call a function from within jsdom at the expressJS scope level.

I'm really hoping this is possible in some manner, as it would greatly simplify my life.

For example:

```
// express
app.get('/someRoute', function(request, response){
    myFunction( request.data, function( getResponse ){
        response.status( 200 ).send( getResponse );
    }
})

//jsdom
jsdom.env('html', function(err, window) {
    .....

    myFunction( a, callback ){
        // <some jquery-only feature that I need>
        callback(a);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, you have several options. I suppose these two parts will be in different files, otherwise you could just define a variable at the top of the file and assign it inside `jsdom`. Depending on how big your app is you may want to choose one or another:

The fast but not great one: Inside the `jsdom.env` function, define a global function, which will be accessible from the ExpressJS router.

```
// express
app.get('/someRoute', function(request, response){
    global.myJSDomFunction(request.data, function( getResponse ){
        response.status( 200 ).send( getResponse );
    }
})
//jsdom
jsdom.env('html', function(err, window) {
    .....

    global.myJSDomFunction = myFunction( a, callback ){
        // <some jquery-only feature that I need>
        callback(a);
    }
})
```

Ok, defining global variables is generally not recommended, in order to maintain a sane architecture and don't generate name collisions. Let's try to define a third file where you can attach your function:

```
// express
const fnContainer = require('../fnContainer')
app.get('/someRoute', function(request, response){
  fnContainer.myJSDomFunction(request.data, function( getResponse ){
    response.status( 200 ).send( getResponse );
  }
})

//jsdom
const fnContainer = require('../fnContainer')
jsdom.env('html', function(err, window) {
  .....

  fnContainer.myJSDomFunction = myFunction( a, callback ){
    // <some jquery-only feature that I need>
    callback(a);
  }
})

//fnContainer.js
module.exports = {
  myJSDomFunction: null,
}
```

The best would be to improve the names depending on your case. You can have more complex structures, at the end, the lesson is that you have to save this function in a place that is accessible from inside the Express.js route.